# Does Hibernate add parent automatically when child was added?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following class structure:

```
public class User{
    Set<UserAttribute> userAttributes;
}

public class Role implements/extends UserAttribute {
    Set<PermissionAssignment> permissionAssignments;
}

public class PermissionAssignment {
    Permission permission;
}

public class Permission implements/extends UserAttribute {
}
```

So, the user has set or attributes. An attribute can be role or permission. Attributes are stored in the same table and I use discriminator. Then the role has set of permission assignments and permission assignment has permission.
Let's assume that I have instance of User class in Hibernate session. What I have to do if I want to add new permission assignment to permission assignments set? Is it enough to create permission assignment, then create permission and call permissionAssignments.add(permission) and then all necessary rows will be created - permission assignment and permission or do I have to add created permission to userAttributes and then create permission assignment and add it to permissionAssignments set? So basically will the Hibernate create the permission row in database when I don't add it to userAttributes set?

If don't what will occur when I add the permissionAssignment and update the User? Will the Hibernate throw any exception which shows why didn't add it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Role` add one method to add `PermissionAssignment` as below:

```
public void addPermissionAssignment(PermissionAssignment permissionAssignment){
   if(this.permissionAssigments == null){
       this.permissionAssigments = new HashSet<PermissionAssigment>();
   }
   permissionAssignment.setRole(this);//this will set the parent
   this.permissionAssigmentsadd(permissionAssignment);
}
```

Use the above method to add `PermissionAssignment` to `Role`.

Hibernate will take care the rest. i.e. creating the `Role` and setting generated primary key as the foreign key in `PermissionAssignment`.

Comment: Permission does not contain permissionAssigments.Role contains permissionAssigments.

Comment: @user1802311: It wasn't very clear to me looking at the object hierarchy. So you want to same Role with PermissionAssignments? If so, same applies there as well. I updated the answer.

Comment: PermissionAssigment does not contain Role. Only Role contains set of PermissionAssigments. And User contains set of UserAttribute which are Permissions and Roles. My question is if I add new PermissionAssigment which contains Permission to set in Role do I need to add this Permission which is in the new PermissionAssigment to userAttributes in User? Or will it be created automatically in database?

Comment: @user1802311: I thought you have `Bidirectional Mapping` hence advised that method. Back to your question. If you add the permissionAssignment to the role, then it should be sufficient as Role is already associated with the user.